# Synchronisation failed, dropping peer

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

Whenever I attempt to run geth on the command line, it seems to have trouble syncing with the blockchain. I am absolutely a novice so I could be completely overlooking. I am getting these warnings continuously(This is run on testnet):

```
WARN [04-21|17:40:40] Ancestor below allowance                 peer=20c9ad97c081d633 number=647267 hash=000000…000000 allowance=647267
WARN [04-21|17:40:40] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=20c9ad97c081d633 err="retrieved ancestor is invalid"
```

Please let me know if there is a solution for this. Thank you!

Comment: It's also important to note that this is on the testnet

Comment: Which version of Geth are you running? How many peers do you see in the output of `admin.peers()`? (Don't really have any ideas on this... )

Comment: 1.5.9 and where do I enter that command? The geth console? If so, I'm getting a 'peers' is not a function error

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue using geth v1.6.1-stable-021c3c28, [deployed on Ubuntu on Microsoft Azure](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/go-ethereum-on-ubuntu). Testnet, same as OP.

Comment: In my case it happend because very old synchronization run long time ago. If it is your case, just delete all *.ldb files from ~/.ethereum/testnet/chaindata/ directory. Hope it will help.

Comment: Have you tried using the --fast and --cache=1024 flags?

Answer (score 7):

I received this error as well.

I deleted everything in the folder `/Users/name/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata` and then restarted with the command `geth --testnet --fast` and it started working

Answer (score 2):

Ethereum testnet has different versions, now the main testnet is called Ropsten. you can see all of the ongoing Ethereum testnets here: [testnet.etherscan.io](https://testnet.etherscan.io/)

It should be noted that Ropsten testnet was attacked in Feb/March 2017, which lead to a fork on the testnet to revive the network. More to read here: [Ropsten Revival](https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten/blob/master/revival.md)

To use the revived version, you need to remove the database and start resyncing using the revived nodes: [Ropsten testnet PoW chain](https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten)

Answer (score 2):

I did the following:

`➜  ~ rm -rf ~/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata`

Then:

`➜  ~ geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"`

And it should works

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, where my chain was just perpetually ~90 blocks away from current. Restarting geth fixed it for me, luckily.