# How does Mist connect to Ropsten?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, connections

I have both Mist and Geth installed. One note though; Mist uses (is bundled with?) Geth 1.6.0 whereas I have Geth 1.6.1 installed.

When I type `> geth --testnet --fast console`, I fail to sync the testnet. After some block, I start to get only messages like this (copied from [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15403/synchronisation-failed-dropping-peer)):

```
WARN [04-21|17:40:40] Ancestor below allowance peer=20c9ad97c081d633 number=647267 hash=000000…000000 allowance=647267 WARN [04-21|17:40:40] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer peer=20c9ad97c081d633 err="retrieved ancestor is invalid"
```

However, when I close this terminal (remove chain data) and start Mist and click "Use the test network", it syncs with Ropsten correctly. Is Mist passing other flags that I need to use too? Or is it just a problem with Geth 1.6.1?

Thanks,

Comment: I see only warnings in the log. Do you have any error messages?

Comment: @IgorBarinov No, but after these warnings, the peers drop so it cannot continue syncing.

Comment: I see, and no more error messages? You know there is an ancient logic trick "after this, therefore because of this"

Comment: OK, I will check in more detail. Hopefully I will update again in a few hours. Thanks