# Testnet blockchain sync stuck at Ancestor below allowance

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I am expereincing problem while syncing testnet with tail of log:

```
WARN [01-09|06:53:30] Ancestor below allowance                 peer=1061607032be098f number=1082429 hash=000000…000000 allowance=1082429
WARN [01-09|06:53:30] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=1061607032be098f err="retrieved ancestor is invalid"
WARN [01-09|06:54:46] Ancestor below allowance                 peer=a6134934cc2d3f31 number=1082429 hash=000000…000000 allowance=1082429
WARN [01-09|06:54:46] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a6134934cc2d3f31 err="retrieved ancestor is invalid"
```

Already asked at -
[Synchronisation failed, dropping peer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15403/synchronisation-failed-dropping-peer)
However I do not want to delete whole of data. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happen usually when peers are disconnect (reject or whatever), you can ignore it. Your geth is actually syncing with network and you must wait.

Comment: Its been like this for a few hours now. Also, `eth.syncing` gives `false`. Is all this normal?

Comment: if the `eth.syncing` returns false then your geth node is synced. What the output of `eth.blockNumber`?

Comment: 1172429
Also, this(1172429) was shown as highest block when it was syncing

Comment: What the network id you're using? Ropsten Kovan?

Comment: I used `--testnet` flag, which I assume uses Ropsten network. And I just came to know the highest block there is 24xxxxx

Comment: Could you provide full `geth` command with all options and the log file. I doubt about blocknumber.

Comment: ` ./build/bin/geth --testnet --syncmode "full" --cache 2048 `

Comment: I suggest you to remove current `~/.ethereum` folder(`rm -rf ~/.ethereum`), and start again with `fast` options. Run with `fast` `./build/bin/geth --testnet --fast --cache=2048 console`. I've used the `fast` option and don't have any problems.